# Transform stroke effect into typing path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, selections, cs3

I'm using Photoshop CS3.

Let's say I made an ellipse selection. I filled it with colour, then I add an outside stroke effect.

I would like to make that stroke effect into a circular path.

I tried magnet selection and using different options of the pen tool, but I can't rely on my mouse nor my hands.

I then tried making an ellipse using the ellipse tool on a new layer. Filled that layer with a colour, than created an outline stroke of about 5 px. Now, I would like to use that outline stroke as a path for typing.

Comment: you want to transform an ellipse selection into a text path? why not just use the ellipse tool?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are exactly trying to achieve? It's a bit unclear. If you want to create a round/circular text path you can just draw a circle with the ellipse tool and use the type tool on it. It will automatically create curved text.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Here is what I did : Made an ellipse using the ellipse tool on a new layer. Filled that layer with a colour, than created an outline stroke of about 5 px. Now, I would like to use that outline stroke as a path for typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making the Ellipse make sure its set to Shape on the top. The options are Pixel, Shape or Path. Pretty sure these were introduced in CS2.

Now with your ellipse shape created press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to duplicate the layer with the ellipse on it.

<kbd>T</kbd> for the Text tool and then move the cursor over the ellipse until you get a wavy line like so:

[image]

I don't have a screenshot tool handy that can capture cursor so sketched it in roughly lol but yeah look for that. It won't work though if your Ellipse is created with Pixels. Then just type:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! The layer duplication actually made what I wanted to do even easier. As I can enlarge the second ellipse anyway I want without having to resort to the thickness of an outline stroke ! Thank you for everything, the edit, the explanation, the illustration, the upvote (the downvote made me feel guilty for my ignorance)  You rule [ : !